# Check if a characters occurs once in URL

Tags: php

**My Question**

I want to check if the URL contains one `?` if true, `do something`

**My PHP**

Im using this script currently.

```
$lp_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // or taken from another source //
    if( strpos($lp_uri, '?') !== false ){
    echo '<script>alert("one question mark");</script>';
}
```

**My Issue**

Im not sure how to check if the`?` occurs **once only**. Can you please help? Thanks heaps

**The reason**

I have a contact form on my website and once someone submits it, it addds a parameter to the url so it look like `website.com?msgsent=1`. This means the message has been send. But sometimes if the `email` field is incorrect, it still adds a `?` to the url so the url looks like `website.com?`.

Now, I am using a jQuery `slideDown` delay on my contact form to grab customers attention and everytime the page refreshes, it takes few seconds to `slideDown`. I want to overcome this if the url has a `?` in it because if the url looks `website.com?` that means, the email address is wrong.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Technically, there shouldn't be more than one `?` in the URL in the first place. What kind of URLs do you have to deal with?

Comment: Ok. I'll update the question

Comment: you should you be fixing your js, not adding php to work around broken js

Comment: @Dagon: true, but he also shouldn't rely only on js, so a server side validation is needed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for the initial question (just in case someone will find this question on google) is to use `substr_count`:

```
if(substr_count($text, '?') == 1){
    // do something
}
```

The solution to your problem would be to check if the `msgsent` parameter is set:

```
if(!isset($_GET['msgsent'])){
    // message not sent - do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution making use of the offset optional parameter

```
<?php
if( strpos($lp_uri, '?') !== false ){ 
   //1 or more question marks
   $pos = strpos($lp_uri, '?');  //Grab the position of it
   if(strpos($lp_uri, '?',$pos) === false) {
      //No more after the first, hence only 1
   }
}
```